# FLUTTER - How to prevent a RiveAnimationController from reset when the playback finishes?

Tags: flutter, animation, controller, rive

I am using the Rive package in order to have some nice animations within my Flutter application and I have 2 doubts:

I have a simple animation where some docs gets animated. I want to play this animation on Tap of it, so I'm using `OneShotAnimation`. The play on tap works, however when the animation ends, it immediately gets reset to the first frame.
When I load the page, in addition, the animation is loaded from the last frame.
How to avoid those 2 problems?

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rive/rive.dart';

class Square extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget page;
  final String title;

  const Square({
    required this.page,
    required this.title,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Square> createState() => _SquareState();
}

class _SquareState extends State<Square> {
  late RiveAnimationController _esamiController;
  bool _isPlaying = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _esamiController = OneShotAnimation(
      'Animation 1',
      autoplay: false,
      onStart: () => setState(() => _isPlaying = true),
      onStop: () => setState(() => _isPlaying = false),
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _esamiController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => _isPlaying ? null : _esamiController.isActive = true,
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 192,
        height: 192,
        child: Card(
          color: Colors.black26,
          elevation: 10,
          child: Center(
            child: RiveAnimation.asset(
              'assets/animations/esami.riv',
              controllers: [_esamiController],
              onInit: (_) => setState(() {}),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Animation not working]
As you can see the sheets should start unordered and end ordered, while here I get the opposite.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: Can you provide sample rive ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used your code and a sample rive's community-made animation to reproduce the issue. If I understood your needs right, here are the two solutions:

1- If you take a look at the source code of rive's controller(`OneShotAnimation`) that you use in your application:

`one_shot_controller.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:rive/src/controllers/simple_controller.dart';

/// Controller tailered for managing one-shot animations
class OneShotAnimation extends SimpleAnimation {
  /// Fires when the animation stops being active
  final VoidCallback? onStop;

  /// Fires when the animation starts being active
  final VoidCallback? onStart;

  OneShotAnimation(
    String animationName, {
    double mix = 1,
    bool autoplay = true,
    this.onStop,
    this.onStart,
  }) : super(animationName, mix: mix, autoplay: autoplay) {
    isActiveChanged.addListener(onActiveChanged);
  }

  /// Dispose of any callback listeners
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    isActiveChanged.removeListener(onActiveChanged);
  }

  /// Perform tasks when the animation's active state changes
  void onActiveChanged() {
    // If the animation stops and it is at the end of the one-shot, reset the
    // animation back to the starting time
    if (!isActive) {
      reset();
    }
    // Fire any callbacks
    isActive
        ? onStart?.call()
        // onStop can fire while widgets are still drawing
        : WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) => onStop?.call());
  }
}
```

As we can see in the `source code`, it `resets` the animation when it ends. So there is nothing to do if you want to use `OneShotAnimation`. The only way is that you can fork the `source code` and change the related line. And add a `modified` version to your project.

`one_shot_controller.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:rive/src/controllers/simple_controller.dart';

/// Controller tailered for managing one-shot animations
class OneShotAnimation extends SimpleAnimation {
  /// Fires when the animation stops being active
  final VoidCallback? onStop;

  /// Fires when the animation starts being active
  final VoidCallback? onStart;

  OneShotAnimation(
    String animationName, {
    double mix = 1,
    bool autoplay = true,
    this.onStop,
    this.onStart,
  }) : super(animationName, mix: mix, autoplay: autoplay) {
    isActiveChanged.addListener(onActiveChanged);
  }

  /// Dispose of any callback listeners
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    isActiveChanged.removeListener(onActiveChanged);
  }

  /// Perform tasks when the animation's active state changes
  void onActiveChanged() {
    // Fire any callbacks
    isActive
        ? onStart?.call()
        // onStop can fire while widgets are still drawing
        : WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) => onStop?.call());
  }
}
```

I have already tried it out, and it works as you wanted. But running animation for the second time could be problematic. For that, please check the second solution.

2- You can use SimpleAnimation. Please check the following solution:

```
class Square extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const Square({
    required this.title,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Square> createState() => _SquareState();
}

class _SquareState extends State<Square> {
  late SimpleAnimation _esamiController;

  bool get isPlaying => _esamiController.isActive;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _esamiController = SimpleAnimation('bell', autoplay: false);

    super.initState();
  }

  void _reset() {
    if (!isPlaying) {
      _esamiController.reset();
    }
  }

  Future<void> _togglePlay() async {
    if (isPlaying) return;

    _reset();
    _esamiController.isActive = true;

    await Future.delayed(
      const Duration(milliseconds: 20),
    );

    _esamiController.isActive = true;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _esamiController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: _togglePlay,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 192,
              height: 192,
              child: Card(
                color: Colors.black26,
                elevation: 10,
                child: Center(
                  child: RiveAnimation.asset(
                    'assets/alarm.riv',
                    controllers: [_esamiController],
                    onInit: (_) => setState(() {}),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

As you can see, I have changed `RiveAnimationController` with the `SimpleAnimation` to access the `reset` method. Because another way, once the animation runs, there is no way to run it for a second time through `RiveAnimationController`.

If you have further problems, please don't hesitate to write in the comments.

Note: Don't forget to modify `animationName` and provide a correct asset directory in `RiveAnimation.asset` widget.